# Is this a problem with my code or is it a problem with discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have been trying to get my discord bot online with visual code studio, discord.js,npm. I keep getting this unknown error when I run "node ." in the terminal. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNkZY.png)

Comment: Please do not post images. Post the error message as well as your code in code snippets.

Comment: Also post your node version, as I expect that to be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The [Logical Nullish Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) Operator is only available to the following node versions as you can see on [node.green](https://node.green/#ES2021-features-Logical-Assignment-----basic-support) 
[image: compatibility]

I suggest you to download a node version that is [16 or above](https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/) for it to properly work!